# Django templates folders

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm experimenting with Django, and figuring out how to set **urls.py**, and how the URLs work.
I've configured **urls.py** in the root of the project, to directs to my blog and admin.
But now I want to add a page to my home, so at `localhost:8000`.

So I've added to following code to the **urls.py** in the root of the project:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r"^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "base.html"}),
)
```

The problem is that it searches for the template in **blog/templates/...**
Instead of the templates folder in my root. Which contains the **base.html**.

Full **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r"^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "base.html"}),
    url(r'^blog/', include('hellodjango.blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
)
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Can you please post your full urls.py?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Did you set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py`? Check and make sure it is set up correctly with absolute paths. This is how I make sure it is properly set:

## settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

This way, I have a `templates` folder in my project root that is used for non-app templates and each app has a `templates/appname` folder inside the app itself.

If you want to use a template from the root template folder, you just give the name of the template like `'base.html'` and if you want to use an app template, you use `'appname/base.html'`

Folder structure:

```
project/
  appname/
    templates/ 
      appname/  <-- another folder with app name so 'appname/base.html' is from here
        base.html
    views.py
    ...

  templates/    <-- root template folder so 'base.html' is from here
    base.html

  settings.py
  views.py
  ...
```

Comment: Thx! I modified the settings in setteings.py, and everything is working as intended! thx alot :) i still find it hard to figure out some poblems which has to do with the settings.py. Im glad it's working. Thx alot!

Comment: @KevinvanHengst No problem, when I started I ran into similar problems and had to go digging for an answer for quite a while, glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm doing this now and app templates work, but extending a project template doesn't. Template loader keeps searching only within the app folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is good, for django 1.9 the variable you want to update is "DIRS" located in "TEMPLATES =" and since the default project root is BASE_DIR it should look like this in the TEMPLATES dict: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),],

Comment: this method is deprecated in Django +1.9.

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/', include('hellodjango.blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^', 'direct_to_template', {"template": "base.html"}),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would re-organize the urls as such:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    (r'^blog/', include('hellodjango.blog.urls')),
    (r'^$', direct_to_template, {"template": "base.html"}),
)
```

Patterns are matched by their specificity, so I tend to put the more specific patterns first. Otherwise you might see some unexpected behavior. Give that a try, and if it's still loading a template from your blog on a request to `/`, we'll dig deeper.

Comment: It's still trying to load templates from blog/templates. I've looked into the settings.py if i screwed up something with TEMPLATE_DIR, but didnt specify one. So im still curious how it gets this path.

Comment: I would recommend setting a templates directory.

Comment: Yes, look into the ``TEMPLATE_DIR`` in ``settings.py`` and you'll find something. Read more about that setting in Django documentation and you'll probably fix it.

Comment: @Brandon Would the ordering matter in this scenario? He properly terminates the regex for the root with `$` so that would only match the root url `/` I get that ordering it like that would be more readable, just wondering if it would actually affect where django looks for templates.

Comment: Also confused by the missing `url` before 2 of the patterns lol

Comment: Yes, the there's really no need to have url specified for a set of patterns you're including. I think the problem is caused by not specifying a templates directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends what you want your home page to be. If its simply a page with links off to other parts of your site then [catherine's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412263/1199394) answer is a nice clean way.

If you want the root of your site to be your blog for example I would do this:

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Django Admin
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # Tiny MCE Urls
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    # Other App
    url(r'^other/', include('projectname.other.urls', namespace='other')),
    # Blog App
    url(r'^', include('projectname.blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
)
```

Also don't forget to name space your url includes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the my solution

```
Django==3.2.5
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420097/10852018