# Can't change Django admin template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

just started [an official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/#customizing-your-project-s-templates) and already ran into a problem, can't change page name in admin panel. I'm trying to replace a default `Django administration` with something custom in the `base_site.html` as suggested in the tutorial (a file which I copied from the django source directory into my app, tried to move it in/out polls directory etc.),
I have added in settings `TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`, and in `installed apps` also `'polls',` but nothing changes.

Any suggestions what I can do in order to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It will not work if you only change the value inside the parentheses like this

```
{{ site_header|default:_('Your custom name') }}
```

What you need to do is you must replace all of the above with your desired name like this.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | YOUR CUSTOM NAME{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">YOUR CUSTOM NAME</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a templates folder at the root level of my Django Site.

```
base-folder 
--apps
--templates 
----admin 
------base_site.html
```

I edited base_site.html like I wanted, I just changed the name like you are trying to. Then I added this line into my settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

This worked for me. If you are seeing the admin site when you type /admin that means your `url-config` is set. Just make sure that your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` matches the directory of the admin template. You should have `admin` directory within the `templates` directory that contains all the necessary templates for the admin page.

Comment: I have exactly the same settings/project hierarchy. Still didn't work.

Comment: @ikechi and you are sure that you saved the edits to the base_site.html?

Comment: @ikechi and your settings file also hase the variable BASE_DIR correctly set up? You might want to check the top answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411164/django-templates-folders)

Comment: changing to `abspath` doesn't help.  I really don't know what is the problem.