# Django path to templates folder in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I am newly learning Django and was following the **Learn Django 1.11** Tutorial.

Here is my current project tree:

```
├── manage.py
├── muypicky
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── old_settings.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py      # Contains the settings (like shown in the tutorial)
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── requirements.txt
├── restaurants
└── templates           # Templates Folder
└── index.html
```

I am trying to add the path to the tempelates folder in the settings folder. But the error shown

> django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: .../muypicky/tempelates/index.html (Source does not exist)

Current setting.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [{
  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tempelates')], 
  },]
```

Looking at the error, the file path is wrong because it goes into /muypicky/tempelates which is incorrect. So how do I get to root folder and then into tempelates folder with the given file tree in setting.py (base.py).

Any further queries, just ask and many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: It would probably help if you were consistent in your own names.  Do you mean `Templates` or `Tempelates`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411164/django-templates-folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same project tree and in TEMPLATES I put :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 4):

You have probably misspelled the name because the directory is called **templates**  but your `settings.py` is looking for **templates**

```
├── manage.py
...
└── templates           # Templates Folder
└── index.html
```

but in your settings you stated `templates`

```
TEMPLATES = [{
  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], 
  },]
```

That's why Djagno can't find the file

.../muypicky/**templates**/index.html (Source does not exist)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Even after fixing the spelling error, I still get '''muypicky/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)'''. I think it's more to do with the BASE_DIR in base.py whis is like this: '''BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))'''

Comment: Also to note, when I add the exact path on my system to the templates folder, it does work, which is why I think it's my BASE_DIR causing the issue.

Comment: Haha, your fix to include his misspelt templates is both humourous and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Typo. Change 'tempelates' to 'templates'.

Answer (score 0):

your Index.html file actually not at
muypicky/templates/index.html
Its in
current project/index.html
So you need to move that index.html file to your
muypicky/templates/ location or

you need to keep it as in BASE_Dir folder settings

Comment: yes you put BASE directory as Template folder but in django it creates all folder then inside it expect template folder where it always look for index.html file. you can do in your current project inside one template folder then you move index.html inside then It will work.